# Do SQL Server compressed indexes remain compressed on rebuild without specifying data compression?

Tags: sql-server, index, compression, data-pages

After one rebuilds their SQL Server indexes using page compression (`ALTER INDEX IX1 REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)`), do subsequent rebuilds (as done by some maintenance scripts past a certain fragmentation threshold) need to specify data compression again? Would the indexes otherwise be effectively decompressed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Indexes remain compressed when rebuilding / reorganizing them.

**Create table and compressed index**

```
 CREATE TABLE DBO.TEST_INDX(id int, bla varchar(255));
 CREATE INDEX IX1 ON dbo.TEST_INDX(id)  WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);
```

**Check Compression**

```
 SELECT i.name, p.data_compression_desc 
 FROM sys.partitions P
 INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = P.object_id AND I.index_id = P.index_id
 WHERE P.data_compression > 0 and I.name = 'IX1';
```

**Result**

```
name    data_compression_desc
IX1     PAGE
```

**Rebuild the index**

```
ALTER INDEX IX1 on  DBO.TEST_INDX rebuild
```

**Check Compression**

```
 SELECT i.name, p.data_compression_desc 
 FROM sys.partitions P
 INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = P.object_id AND I.index_id = P.index_id
 WHERE P.data_compression > 0 and I.name = 'IX1'
```

**Result**

```
name    data_compression_desc
IX1     PAGE
```

---

**Disabling them and then rebuilding has a different result, since disabling removes the index, while keeping the index definition.**

```
alter index IX1 on  DBO.TEST_INDX DISABLE ;
alter index IX1 on  DBO.TEST_INDX REBUILD ;
```

**Result**

```
name    data_compression_desc
```

*Compression was lost, compression definition would also be lost when dropping and creating the index via SSMS without adapting the Index create script.*

*Why?*

*Because the data_compression option is not retained when scripting out the Index create statement.*

**however, if we disable the index , rebuild with compression and then rebuild again:**

```
alter index IX1 on  DBO.TEST_INDX DISABLE ;
alter index IX1 on  DBO.TEST_INDX REBUILD  WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);
alter index IX1 on  DBO.TEST_INDX REBUILD;
```

**Result**

```
name    data_compression_desc
IX1 PAGE
```

---

**Testing a rebuild with Ola hallengren's maintenance solution**

*The parameters are modified for testing purposes.*

Add some data to get to one page, as it is needed for the MinNumberOfPages parameter.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_INDX(id,bla)
VALUES(5,'test');
go 10
```

Execute the index optimize proc to print out the statement.

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'TestDB',
@FragmentationLow = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@Indexes = 'TestDB.DBO.TEST_INDX',
@Execute = 'N',
@MinNumberOfPages = 1;
```

**Result:**

```
Command: ALTER INDEX [IX1] ON [TestDB].[dbo].[TEST_INDX] REBUILD WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = ON, RESUMABLE = OFF)

Comment: ObjectType: Table, IndexType: NonClustered, ImageTex
t: No, NewLOB: No, FileStream: No, ColumnStore: No, AllowPageLocks: Yes, PageCount: 1, Fragmentation: 0
Outcome: Not Executed
Duration: 00:00:00
Date and time: 2019-01-09 14:48:12
```

**Executing the generated command**

```
ALTER INDEX [IX1] ON [TestDB].[dbo].[TEST_INDX] REBUILD WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = ON, RESUMABLE = OFF)
```

**Compression is retained**

```
name    data_compression_desc
IX1 PAGE
```

---

**Testing a rebuild with a maintenance plan (I would strongly argue for ola's solution)**

Rebuild indexes

[image]

Choose the test table

[image]

Add some test fragmentation levels.

[image]

Insert some values to get the fragmentation going

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_INDX(id)
SELECT id from TEST_INDX
go 4
```

Check the fragmentation percentage

```
SELECT 
I.[name] AS  INDX ,
IPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
IPS.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), object_id('[dbo].[TEST_INDX]'), NULL, NULL, NULL) AS IPS
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS I ON I.[object_id] = IPS.[object_id]
AND IPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE IPS.database_id = DB_ID()
and I.name = 'IX1'
```

Result

```
INDX    avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
IX1 66,6666666666667    3
```

Run the plan

[image]

**The interesting part here, when looking at the plan report, is that the `DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE` option is added to the generated `REBUILD` command!**

```
Command:USE [TestDB]
GO
ALTER INDEX [IX1] ON [dbo].[TEST_INDX] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, RESUMABLE = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
```

Fragmentation:

```
INDX    avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
IX1 0   2
```

Compression:

```
name    data_compression_desc
IX1 PAGE
```

Comment: I came across you post when I found that 3 databases I had compressed had all lost their compression & I had to reapply it. As part of that work, I tested & confirmed your results but have no idea how this happened. The only other possibility that I have come across is that, if indexes are disabled, they lose compression when rebuilt. This does not appear to be the case, per our ETL team. I've also posed this question on SQLServerCentral: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/2017336/Databases-Lost-Compression Totally at a loss for how this happened.

Comment: Hi @Marvel, it could be that some other process recreated indexes on the databases? For example some applications do 'upgrades' where they drop and create countless indexes. However I do not  think that anybody will be able to give a clear-cut explanation without more details. Next time it happens, you could find the index creation date, and find if they where recreated (e.g. with the query in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579932/get-index-creation-date-from-sql-server. Otherwise you could always ask as a question, but I do think that you would need to provide more info.

Comment: Thanks, Randi! I set up SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP auditing on the databases but this will definitely help me to parse through the logs faster. I have already found one of the culprits- the owner of the databases, the one who requested the compression has been modifying tables & indexes constantly. He did not realize that when he created new tables & moved the old data in & creating new indexes would cause compression to be lost. :( I have provided him with the correct way to create his tables & indexes. I don't think he is the only culprit, however. I cannot imagine that he has done this to e

Comment: @RandiVertongen - Bloody awesome post, Randi.  Thanks for the time you spend putting it together.

Comment: @JeffModen thanks a bunch! It means a lot coming from a SQL Server legend as yourself! (I still unfortunately have to use the RBAR term towards customers these days ;)) Hope all is well.

Comment: @RandiVertongen - Heh... thanks for the awesome compliment but I don't consider myself as a "legend" especially since I'm still on this side of the dirt: :D  I do have a suggestion though... you could help a lot more people and become a bit of a legend yourself especially since it's difficult to find the answer to that question in the actual MS documentation.  With that, consider writing an article over at SQL Server Central or for the Simple-Talk websites.  I'd even do a full technical review for you before you hit the "Submit" button.  And, they pay you for articles. :D