# data compression does not show when scripting index on ssms

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, ssms, compression

when I right click on SSMS and choose to script the create index:

[image]

I get this script, without the data_compression:

```
USE [APCore]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [i_agencyId]    Script Date: 07/11/2019 12:18:13 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [i_agencyId] ON [agy].[agency]
(
    [agencyId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [countryCode]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES]
GO
```

But when specifically checking for the [data compression](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/226685/22336) using teh query below

```
use APCore
go

SELECT i.name, p.data_compression_desc 
 FROM sys.partitions P
 INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = P.object_id AND I.index_id = P.index_id
 WHERE P.data_compression > 0 and I.name = 'i_agencyId';
```

[image]

I get the correct information.

I am using [this SSMS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221349/22336) :

[image]

Is there a way to make ssms include data compression on the index definition when scripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your scripting options are set correctly for Data Compression

[image]